# How expensive are explicit conversions with convert_T() in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42156691/3579977) question, is it possible that the gain in performance obtained by vectorized operations is being offset by the explicit conversions with convert_T()? Note that the default type of the variable is `unsigned char`. I am using OpenCL 2.0. My GPU is Intel HD Graphics 530 (Gen9).

Will it make a difference between `convert_int4()` and `convert_short4()`?

Comment: it could be hardware dependent. if hardware has it, fast, and if drivers emulate it, slow.

Comment: Yeah, your best bet is to check what kind of assembly your platform generates

Comment: You could try your own bit hack magic but would  only be fast on an fpga.

Comment: Well float to int may need some conversion. But int2short is just shift operation (or a noop if it is later used somewhere and the HW can read the LSB of the register). It all depends on the case.

Comment: @DarkZeros which is used for (float to int / int to float)? FP32 logic units or integer logic units or completely different but just a few special units?